# Problem with angular 15 and firebase 9.1 - FirebaseError: Expected type 'Ac', but it was: a custom wh object

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs-observables

i've correctly done the setup of angular and firebase web-app,

but i still struggle with this error:

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbLcG.png)

module class :

```
import { NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Firestore } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import { provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';


import {environment} from 'src/environments/environment';



import { getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())
  ],
  providers: [IsAuthFake],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule implements OnInit{}
```

and the component where i'm using the firestore is the following:

```
  constructor(private _bottomSheet: MatBottomSheet,private firestore: Firestore ) {

    const userProfileCollection = collection(this.firestore, 'users');

    // get documents (data) from the collection using collectionData
    this.users$ = collectionData(userProfileCollection) as Observable<MatchModel[]>

    this.users$.subscribe(e => console.log(e)) // problems starts here

  }

  openBottomSheet(): void {
    this._bottomSheet.open(BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet);
  }
}
```

any ideas?

thank you in advance

i'm just trying to connect firebase to my angular project.
angular : 15.2
firebase: 9.1
firebase-tools: 11.21

Comment: Run the app in devMode to have the symbols in your error log.

Comment: This looks suspicious: `const collection = collection(this.firestore, 'users')`. Did you mean for it to be: `const userProfileCollection = collection(this.firestore, 'users')`?

Comment: i've edited the code and missed that before publication, but the main error is still there